# Matching underlying row values with the column headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

could you assist with mapping underlying row values with the header values. I have a few data-sets im scraping from the web, which include a dollar value as well as quantities. I created custom headers to represent the column names instead of using the scraped quantities.

**Context**
If I had the following arrays and custom table headers:

```js
columns=['1-9','10-99','100-249','250-359', '360-1079','1080-2519', '2520-5039','5040-10790','10800+'])

#arrays
qunatity1 = ['1', '10', '100', '250', '360', '1,080', '2,520', '5,040', '10,080']
quantity2 = ['1', '10', '100', '250', '510', '1,020', '2,550', '5,100', '10,200']
quantity 3 = ['1', '10', '25', '100', '250', '360', '1,080', '2,520']

dollar_val_1 = ['$1.63', '$1.55', '$1.26', '$1.20', '$1.14', '$1.13', '$1.10', '$1.06', '$1.03']
dollar_val_2 = ['$1.63', '$1.55', '$1.26', '$1.20', '$1.14', '$1.13', '$1.10', '$1.06', '$1.03']
dollar_val_3 = ['$1.24', '$1.19', '$1.07', '$0.963', '$0.919', '$0.873', '$0.845', '$0.822']
```

so based on the quantity(1,2,3) arrays id like to match the matching dollar(1,2,3) arrays and place the dollar values under the custom column headers.
**PS:**
the quantity arrays are only needed to ensure that the that the dollar values are matched with the underlying column headers
Is this possible. if yes how would I do it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sample is not reproducible. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

Take your first pair of arrays as an example,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'q': quantity1, 'dollar_val': dollar_val_1})
```

First we need `'q'` as integer,

```
df1['q'] = df1['q'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

`pd.cut` is the method for custom-binning your data, so you may define your bining range as follow,

```
bins = [1,10, 100, 250, 360, 1080, 2520, 5040, 10080]
```

and use it in `pd.cut` with arguments as shown below. [Explanation to the arguments.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
df1['quantity'] = pd.cut(df1['q'], bins=bins, include_lowest=True, right=False)\
    .apply(lambda t: f'{t.left}-{t.right-1}')\
    .astype(str)\
    .replace('nan', np.nan)\
    .fillna((df1['q'] >= bins[-1]).map({True: '10080+'}))
```

`apply` and `astype` take care of formats, and `replace` and `fillna` place `'10080+'` into the column, because the way we use `pd.cut` won't extend binning outside of the bins boundaries.

```
Lastly, taking care of format again,

df1 = df1.drop(columns='q').set_index('quantity').transpose()
print(df1)

quantity      1-9  10-99 100-249 250-359 360-1079 1080-2519 2520-5039  \
dollar_val  $1.63  $1.55   $1.26   $1.20    $1.14     $1.13     $1.10   

quantity   5040-10079 10080+  
dollar_val      $1.06  $1.03
```